# Url path of File saved in Web Content

Tags: java, servlets

I have saved certain files in server under Web Content. Now i wanted to obtain iots url path, i mean its path starting with http:// not its absolute path, because i wanted to pass the url path as json object to my android  client. Whereas absolute path can't be access in other system, but if its url path then i can access it. Please help me out in resolving this.

Comment: This question appears to be the same topic as your previous question.  Do not just ask the same question.

Comment: Iam not getting proper answer, that why raised separate question

Comment: try editing your answers/comments so that they make more sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
String path=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath();
```

This would give you the path of your project and from there navigate wherever you want.

Comment: Iam having Samuel folder inside WebContent, Inside Samuel Folder i have some pdf  and text files. Now i want to know the url of Samuel folder

Comment: append Samuel to the path string as path=path+"/Samuel". Now you have path of Samuel folder. Simillarly you can append your files as well for their paths.

Comment: It returns me again the real path, i mentioned in my post, i dont wnat real path, i need url

Answer (score 0):

I got answer after a long research

```
String fullContextPath = request.getScheme() + "://"
            + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":"
            + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath()
            + "/PdfToHtml";
```